# multiple or php becomes true?

Tags: php, syntax

I have a problem. This becomes true.

```
$mountain_pump = "n";
if ($mountain_pump != "n" || $mountain != "n" || $mountain_pump != "" || $mountain != "") {
        if ($rot == "Ja"){
            $vibration = 12000;
            $vibration_string = number_format($vibration , 0, ',', '.') . " kr (med ROT-avdrag)";
        } else {
            $vibration = 15000;
            $vibration_string = number_format($vibration , 0, ',', '.') . " kr (utan ROT-avdrag)";
        };
        $summary = $summary + $vibration;
        $printstring = $printstring . "<tr><td>Vibrationsbesiktning:</td><td>" . $vibration_string . "</td></tr>";
    }
```

If I remove this...

```
|| $mountain_pump != "" || $mountain != ""
```

... the script work as intended. I need to have the above "or's" since the value can be "" sometimes.

Anyone have a clue why the script runs even if the value is "n" of $mountain_pump, as in this example?

Comment: If `$mountain_pump` has a value of `n` then `$mountain_pump != ""` will be true

Comment: Perhaps you meant `if (($mountain_pump != "" && $mountain_pump != "n") || ($mountain != "n" && $mountain != "")) {`

Comment: If you wanted to check if *neither* of them is `n` or empty, you'd probably should `and` the conditions.

Comment: Ah, now when you say it. Ofc. :) Need to find a way to run the script if the variables is not "n" or "".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well of course the above condition evaluates to true:

```
$mountain_pump = 'n';
if ($mountain_pump != 'n' || $mountain_pump != '')
```

The condition can only be false if `$mountain_pump` is *neither* `n` nor `''`. If the variable is an empty string, or n, the condition will be true. I don't really see what the problem is, though, just replace the `||` with `&&`  and you're there (The condition should exclude all cases where `$mountain_pump` is `n` or `''`, so you want to exclude condition 1 ***and*** condition 2).

Comment: Thanks all for all help to make me think clear! `(($mountain_pump != "" && $mountain_pump != "n") || ($mountain != "n" && $mountain != ""))` did it.

Comment: @JoakimB: Glad I could help. Please do note that posting _"thank-you"_ comments is discouraged. The SO way to thank answerers is to [mark an answer as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235), which gives you a +2 reputation bonus.

Comment: Ok, will do so in the future.